# How to find the first operator in arithmetic expression?

Tags: c, math, expression, binary-tree

I have this arithmetic expression: `E=((c+(a*b))-(c+(d*e)))`.
I need to find the first operator to put in a binary tree with recursive function

```
typedef struct node  { char info;   struct node*left, *right; } TNode, *Tree;
Tree fBuild ( char *E) // recursive function
Tree aux = (Tree)malloc (sizeof(TNode));  //tree in recursive function
```

First I need to find the first operator, for this example is `'-'`, to make first node and after I make with recursive function for `aux->left` with `E1=(c+(a*b))` and `aux->right` with `E2=(c+(d*e))`

Example

```
          -

      /       \
     /         \
    +           +
  /   \        /  \
 c     *      c    *
      /  \        /  \
     a    b      d     e
```

How can I count the parenthesis or other algorithm to find the first operator in c code?

Comment: What if the expression is `a - b - c`? Hint: use a grammar.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem: you don't need to find that minus to solve your problem. It will emerge as a root node all by itself if you write a simple recursive descent parser.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight True, except that a recursive descent parser respecting operator precedence is fueled by a somewhat non-simple grammar; other parsing approaches yield an equally simple parser implementing an even simpler "grammar" (basically just precedence tables).

Comment: In general, left paren means dive down, right paren means rise up (to the root).

Comment: So it looks like a 'tree' would be a node containing an operation (+-*/) and to children each of which are either variables or trees themselves.

Comment: @delnan This grammar appears to have no operator precedence rules -- just parentheses. That makes for an extremely simple recursive descent parser, one with only two rules and no backtracking.

Comment: yes i have no operator precedence rules, i have just parantheses. As @Adrian McCarthy said i need a parsing technique and make the order of operations implicit in the grammar, but i don't have sufficient knowledge about that. I don't understand this pseudocode. I only programmed in C and i'm a beginner  Expression :== Term | Expression ( '+' | '-' ) Term
Term :== Factor | Term ( '*' | '/' ) Factor
Factor :== value | '(' Expression ')'

Comment: @Sneftel Ah, I jumped to assuming operator precedence without checking the examples provided. Yes, in that case the grammar is simple and the recursive descent parser is almost trivial.

Comment: Walk before you run. Can you write a *lexer*? Get your lexer right before you try to write a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a programming exercise so the standard toolkit of `lec`, `yacc` and standard algorithms like the [Shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) are not available.

The question ask for how to find the top minus sign. To do just that count brackets. Add one for each open bracket, subtract one for each close bracket. In this example the `-` is the only operator with a count of 1. In C assume you have a string s. In C this will be a simple loop through the character of the string.

This will not be the most efficient way of building your tree. You can scan the input one character at a time building partial trees as you go and keeping track of depth.

Comment: I solved the problem and will publish that after the deadline of my homework(3-4)days. Thank everyone for guidance and help

Answer (score 0):

The common solution is to build the tree using a parsing technique such as a recursive descent parser.

You can make the order of operations implicit in the grammar.

```
Expression :== Term | Expression ( '+' | '-' ) Term
Term :== Factor | Term ( '*' | '/' ) Factor
Factor :== value | '(' Expression ')'
```

You have to rearrange the grammar a bit to avoid the left recursion.  Once you do that, you can write a recursive descent grammar by writing a function for each of the grammar rules (e.g., ParseExpression, ParseTerm, and ParseFactor) that takes the current position in the input and returns a new tree node.

Start the parser by calling ParseExpression with the beginning of the input, and you'll get back the root node of the tree.